# How to show loading screen class before preferences [Libgdx & android]

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sharedpreferences

So I am programming a game, and implemented preferences to save/load some simple data for sound/high score, nothing too much. The problem is that when I load preferences for the first time on a physical phone (samsung g. s3) it takes about 15sec and on s5 it takes about 5-8secs and in that time it shows black screen even though I have set the loading screen to be shown first, before preferences are used.

In my main application code I set screen to loadingScreen

```
loadingScreen = new com.package.game.Screens.LoadingScreen(this);
mainScreen = new com.package.game.Screens.MainScreen(this);
gameScreen = new com.package.game.Screens.GameScreen(this);
settingsScreen = new com.package.game.Screens.SettingsScreen(this);
this.setScreen(loadingScreen);
```

and then in my loading screen I access preferences:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    this.progress_assets = 0f;
    this.progress_assets = 0f;
    font_loading = app.initFont(50, 1, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    queueAssets();

    loading_db();
}

private void loading_db() {
    if(database.get_first_time()){
        //do some introduction for first time run
        Gdx.app.log("db","first time worked");
        database.set_first_time();
        progress_db=1f;
    }else{
        Gdx.app.log("db","first time is set false");
        progress_db=1f;
    }
}
```

and my preferences class:

```
 package com.package.game.Engine;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
 import com.package.game.Application;

 public class Database {
private Preferences preferences;
//database
private Preferences pref_settings;
private Preferences pref_score;
private Preferences pref_unlocks;
public Database(){
        pref_settings = Gdx.app.getPreferences("com.package.game.settings");
        pref_score = Gdx.app.getPreferences("com.package.game.score");
        pref_unlocks = Gdx.app.getPreferences("com.package.game.unlocks");

}


//checking if first time run
public boolean get_first_time(){
    return pref_settings.getBoolean("First_run",true);

}
public void set_first_time(){
    pref_settings.putBoolean("First_run",false);
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
       pref_unlocks.putBoolean("unlock_"+i,true);
    }
    pref_unlocks.flush();
    pref_settings.flush();
}
//settings
public boolean getSound(){
        return pref_settings.getBoolean("sound_on",true);
}
public void setSound(boolean sound){
    pref_settings.putBoolean("sound_on",sound);
    pref_settings.flush();
}
//High Score Mode:
//Classic
public int getScore_classic(int place){
    return pref_score.getInteger("score_classic_"+place,0);//default value 0 so we could place new score if we havent reached it
}
public void setScore_classic(int place,int scored){
    pref_score.putInteger("score_classic_"+place,scored);
    pref_score.flush();
}
//Recipe
public int getScoreRec(int place){

    return pref_score.getInteger("score_recipe_"+place,0);//default value 0 so we could place new score if we havent reached it
}
public void setScoreRec(int place,int scored){

    pref_score.putInteger("score_recipe_"+place,scored);
    pref_score.flush();
}
//food unlocks
public boolean getFoodUnlock(int unlockID){
    return pref_unlocks.getBoolean("unlock_"+unlockID,false);
}
public void setFoodUnlock(int unlockID,boolean state){
    pref_unlocks.putBoolean("unlock_"+unlockID,state);
    pref_unlocks.flush();
}
}
```

I'm not sure if creating 3 pref. files is good, but i would like to know how to show screen before pref. file being created/loaded.

**Edit:** Adding my main code

```
package com.mindutis.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;
import com.mindutis.game.Screens.LoadingScreen;

public class Application extends Game {
public static  int V_WIDTH ;
public static  int V_HEIGHT;

public OrthographicCamera camera;
public SpriteBatch batch;

public AssetManager assets;
public com.mindutis.game.Screens.LoadingScreen loadingScreen;
public com.mindutis.game.Screens.SplashScreen splashScreen;
public com.mindutis.game.Screens.MainScreen mainScreen;
public com.mindutis.game.Screens.GameScreen gameScreen;
public com.mindutis.game.Screens.SettingsScreen settingsScreen;
public BitmapFont f_game_name;
public String t_game_name;
public String[] font_type = new String[2];
private boolean firstFrame = true;
private boolean loading = true;



@Override
public void create() {

    assets = new AssetManager();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    V_WIDTH= Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    V_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    //Global var.
    //font initializer
    font_type[0] = "fonts/comics_bold.ttf";
    font_type[1] = "fonts/vdj.ttf";
    //game name
    t_game_name = " Catch a\nSandwich";
    f_game_name = initFont(70, 0, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    loadingScreen = new com.mindutis.game.Screens.LoadingScreen(this);
    splashScreen = new com.mindutis.game.Screens.SplashScreen(this);
    mainScreen = new com.mindutis.game.Screens.MainScreen(this);
    gameScreen = new com.mindutis.game.Screens.GameScreen(this);
    settingsScreen = new com.mindutis.game.Screens.SettingsScreen(this);


 //   this.setScreen(loadingScreen);
}

//int size=font size, int x = font type
public BitmapFont initFont(int size, int type, float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
    BitmapFont font;
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(font_type[type]));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = size;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    font.setColor(red / 255f, green / 255f, blue / 255f, alpha);
    return font;
}

@Override
public void render() {
    if (firstFrame){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.2f, .67f, .88f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        f_game_name.draw(batch, t_game_name, camera.viewportWidth / 2 - 150, camera.viewportHeight - 100);
        batch.end();
        firstFrame = false;
    } else {
       if(loading){
           loading=false;
           loadEverything();
       }
        // Notice you don't actually render anything so what you previously drew stays on the screen.

       }
    super.render();

}
private void loadEverything(){
    // load your font, assets, prefs, etc.

    this.setScreen(loadingScreen);
   // setScreen(loadingScreen);
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    assets.dispose();
    f_game_name.dispose();
    loadingScreen.dispose();
    splashScreen.dispose();
    mainScreen.dispose();
    gameScreen.dispose();
    settingsScreen.dispose();

}

}
```

Loading screen class:

```
package com.mindutis.game.Screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.mindutis.game.Application;
import com.mindutis.game.Engine.Database;

public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {

private final Application app;
private Database database;
private BitmapFont font_loading;
private boolean load;
private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
private Stage stage;

private String t_loading;
private float progress_assets,progress_db;


private boolean firstFrame = true;
private boolean loading = true;

public LoadingScreen(Application app) {
    this.app = app;
    database = new Database();
    this.stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(com.mindutis.game.Application.V_WIDTH, com.mindutis.game.Application.V_HEIGHT, app.camera));
    this.shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    t_loading = "Loading...";
load=false;

}

private void queueAssets() {
    //good food
    //bread
    app.assets.load("img/Food/breadtop.png", Texture.class);

    app.assets.load("img/Food/breadbot.png", Texture.class);
    //rest of the food
    app.assets.load("img/Food/food_sheet.png", Texture.class);
      //misc
    app.assets.load("img/Misc/coin.png", Texture.class);
   app.assets.load("img/Misc/soon.png", Texture.class);
       app.assets.load("img/Misc/shoptriangle.png", Texture.class);
     //buttons
    app.assets.load("img/Buttons/button.png", Texture.class);
     app.assets.load("img/Buttons/soundBT.png", Texture.class);
     app.assets.load("img/Buttons/btX.png", Texture.class);
      app.assets.load("img/Buttons/btShop1.png", Texture.class);
    //human
    app.assets.load("img/Human/human.png", Texture.class);
     app.assets.load("img/Human/human1.png", Texture.class);
       app.assets.load("img/Human/human2.png", Texture.class);


}

@Override
public void show() {
    this.progress_assets = 0f;
    this.progress_assets = 0f;
    font_loading = app.initFont(50, 1, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    queueAssets();

    loading_db();
}

private void loading_db() {
    if(database.get_first_time()){
        //do some introduction for first time run
        Gdx.app.log("db","first time worked");
        database.set_first_time();
        progress_db=1f;
    }else{
        Gdx.app.log("db","first time is set false");
        progress_db=1f;
    }
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if (firstFrame){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.2f, .67f, .88f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        app.batch.begin();
        app.f_game_name.draw(app.batch, app.t_game_name, app.camera.viewportWidth / 2 - 150, app.camera.viewportHeight - 100);
        app.batch.end();
        firstFrame = false;
    } else {
        if(loading){
            loading=false;}
             //input
            Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
                @Override
                public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                    if (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.2f, .67f, .88f, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            update(delta);

            app.batch.begin();
            font_loading.draw(app.batch, t_loading, app.camera.viewportWidth / 2 - 150, 123);
            app.f_game_name.draw(app.batch, app.t_game_name, app.camera.viewportWidth / 2 - 150, app.camera.viewportHeight - 100);
            app.batch.end();

            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            shapeRenderer.rect(32, 50, app.camera.viewportWidth - 64, 16);

            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            shapeRenderer.rect(32, 50, (progress_assets+progress_db)/2 * (app.camera.viewportWidth - 64), 16);
            shapeRenderer.end();

        }
        // Notice you don't actually render anything so what you previously drew stays on the screen.

    }






private void update(float delta) {
    progress_assets = MathUtils.lerp(progress_assets, app.assets.getProgress(), .1f);
    if (app.assets.update() && (progress_assets+progress_db)/2 >= app.assets.getProgress() - .01f) {

        app.setScreen(app.mainScreen);
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    shapeRenderer.dispose();
    font_loading.dispose();
    stage.dispose();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly load a single texture to show while everything else loads. Load and show the texture the first time render() is called. Then the second time render() is called, load your stuff, dispose the texture, and switch screens.

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Screen {

    private boolean firstFrame = true;
    private Texture texture;
    private ExtendViewport viewport;
    private MyGame game;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private static final float LOAD_IMAGE_WIDTH = 480, LOAD_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 600;
    // Use whatever the loading image dimensions are.

    public LoadingScreen (MyGame game, SpriteBatch batch){
        this.game = game;
        this.batch = batch;
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(LOAD_IMAGE_WIDTH, LOAD_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height, false);
        viewport.getCamera().position.set(LOAD_IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, LOAD_IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
        viewport.getCamera().update();
    }

    public void show (){} // do nothing

    public void render (float delta) {

        if (firstFrame){
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            viewport.apply();
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
            batch.setBlendingDisabled(true);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, LOAD_IMAGE_WIDTH, LOAD_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
            batch.end();
            firstFrame = false;
        } else {
            loadEverything(); 
            // Notice you don't actually render anything so what you previously drew stays on the screen.
        }
    }

    private void loadEverything(){
        // load your font, assets, prefs, etc.

        texture.dispose();
        main.setGameScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but this didn't helped me. My problem is that i want to show something on screen before preference file is loaded/create. While launching app(fresh install) it kind of seems that whole phone hangs while creating pref. files cuz android catlog doesnt sent anything plus after that hang i get this msg:
 /AndroidGraphics: resumed
after that everything loads neat and fast.

Comment: ??? That's what this does. It shows something on screen before loading anything else.

Comment: Even after adding adding your code, when first time launching app my whole apps kind of hangs and after pref files are created it starts showing screen thats when android graphics are resumed

Comment: Sounds like something else is wrong. Can you show your Game class? Prefs files shouldn't be created until you actually instantiate them. They would add trivial time to loading anyway so they aren't the problem.

Comment: I added code as requested. and preference class is called in loading screen first, will add that too

Comment: You are still loading a bunch of stuff before drawing anything. Your LoadingScreen's constructor loads your Database class, a Stage (which has its own SpriteBatch with big array and shader to compile), and a ShapeRenderer (which also has a big array and shader to compile), and you instantiate the LoadingScreen in Application.create(), which is called before anything gets rendered. And in `show()` you're loading a BitmapFont (a pretty slow operation), so that happens before rendering, too.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you put my code in the LoadingScreen and also in the Game redundantly. If you fix the above problems, there's no reason to do it in the Game class. In your LoadingScreen class, you would move any line with the word `new` into `loadEverything()`, along with `queueAssets()` and `loading_db()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing how loading works. And about loading screen it has a check if databse is loaded first time so it could create few initial default values (in my database unlocks are set to false by  default, but i need some of them to be true, so i check if db is runned first time). Will try later to see if moving everything with 'new' will help.